# Globals.ReportName is truncated if Report Name includes a period: workaround?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, built-in

In my reports I include a separate tablix at the end which contains data useful for troubleshooting. Typically I include the report name, the execution time, the userID and the parameters.

My reports are numbered, so that the RDL file might be named "3.04 RMC Agenda.rdl". When I use the Globals!ReportName built in field to display my report name, all that is output is "3". Help! Is there a work around? Removing the report numbers in the RDL file name is not an option.

Thanks

SSRS 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only an issue in BIDS. When Deployed to SSRS the report name is shown in full.